# Identify Bronze Coloured Beetle

Tags: species-identification

Spotted this beetle on Morfa Nefyn, a beach in North Wales, UK. The beach is a mixture of sand and stone, with large sandy cliff faces and rocky outcrops.

[image: Shiny Bronze Beetle]

The beetle was about 3 to 5 mm or so long, running around on the rocks at the edge of a rock pool (not in the water though!), on a warm sunny day. It was moving are quickly, but not really fast, maybe around 1cm per second.

I've seen them on the beach before and sure I know what they were called but can't for the life of me remember.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you have a Ground Beetle (family Carabidae) here, but I don't know the British complement of that group, so going deeper isn't an option for me.

Answer (score -1):

[Amara aenea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amara_aenea) (Common Sun Beetle)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions inclusion of an uploaded image for comparison will help you get a more favorable response to your posting.  If you can provide details (ideally with references) for what characters led you to this identification that would be even better. ——— You may also wish to take the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then consult the help pages on the standards for how to effectively provide answers — see: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks! 